# Getting a live maximum value from a backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var stooges = [
     {name: 'moe', age: 40}, 
     {name: 'larry', age: 50}, 
     {name: 'curly', age: 60}
];

_.max(stooges, function(stooge){ return stooge.age; });

=> {name: 'curly', age: 60};
```

So `curly` is returned because he is the oldest, he is the max age of the above collection.

P.S (Age might not be the best example) Lets say somehow magically, `larry` has some kind of disease where he ages 12 years for every year and becomes 62 while `curly` only turns 61, how do I detect this change?

In my real app the max value in the collection will change periodically and I would like to have a function that detects a change so I can add stuff to notify the user a change in the max has been made.

I know backbone.js has `changed`, `_previousAttributes`, and other methods but they seem to only return the actual max value and not the previous max value.

Edit: I have a method in my backbone code to get get the max

```
getMax : function(attribute) {
    var home = $('#main').attr('data-home'),
        away = $('#main').attr('data-away')
    return this.collection.max(function (player) {
        return player.get("teamName") === home || player.get("teamName") === away? player.get(attribute) : 0;
    }, this);
}
```

So if I want to get the maximum attribute in my collection I would call `this.getMax("points");` and use that to determine who is my max point leader.

I am not sure how to compare an old value to a changed value, ex. "kevin" has 12 points while "adam" has 10, "kevin" is the current max points, so on click I add 3 points to adam he now has "13" points and is now the leader while "kevin" is the previous leader.

So I cannot figure out how to create a method or statement to detect if there is a change in max value

Edit: change handler

```
// 1 for one point
if(e.keyCode == 49 && !e.ctrlKey || e.keyCode == 97 && !e.ctrlKey) { 
    if(this.$el.hasClass('hover')) {
        var addMake = parseInt(this.model.get('made_one')) + 1;
        var addOnePoint = parseInt(this.model.get('points')) + 1;         
        this.model.save({made_one: addMake, points: addOnePoint});
        feedCollection.create({
            feedItem: 'made a freethrow', 
            playerName: this.model.get('playerName'), 
            teamName: this.model.get('teamName'),
            facebookID: this.model.get('facebookID')
        });
    }
}
```

Okay so the actual event that changes the model is inside a separate view, it's actually a keypress event. I listen to any changes to the collection inside my statistics view which is the view that handles the max values. Inside the statistics view I render it every time there is a change, so if the values do change it automatically puts the appropriate max value, but I am unsure how to detect that change `this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);`.

Comment: You will need to call `_.max` again in the change handler (and compare to the previous result) - you can only find larry's disease by testing them every new year.

Comment: So if I have an event that adds the attribute to the model I would check each time if the previous result changes, how do I capture the old val, I tried storing it in a variable but to no success, could you provide a simple example, easy points.

Comment: Can you show us how you tried it?

Comment: Sure I added some additional info in my post above, basically I have a method that gets the max in my collection, and I am passing it into my template. I render the template when there is a "change" in the collection.

Comment: Could you please also show that `change` event handler (where you call `this.getMax("points")`, render the template and tried to compare the previous values)?

Comment: Okay so I added more to it, I show that I have a view for a single `player` inside that view is where I add data on a keypress event. Inside the `statisticsView` a view that contains the max values (separate from players, but the same collection is passed) I listen to any changes in the collection `this.listenTo(this.collection, "change", this.render);` re-rendering the view to show the appropriate max value at all times, I am just unsure how to detect if it has changed.

Comment: I havent tried comparing, because I am not sure how to do that when I dont know how to store the old value. In a previous version I did a hack and stored the max inside a `data-attribute` and listened if that value changed. This time around I want a cleaner less complicated/messy solution. The reason for this is just to have more power/control over what is happening so that I can run animations/notifications at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a sort function for the collection

```
class People extends Backbone.Collection
  comparator: (p1, p2) ->
    if p1.get("age") > p2.get("age") then -1 else 1

var stooges = 
     {name: 'moe', age: 40}
     {name: 'larry', age: 50}
     {name: 'curly', age: 60}

people = new People(stooges)

# whenever age changes, the people's order will be changed accordingly
people.on "change", people.sort, people

# so people.at(0) will always be the biggest
# people.at(1) will be the last biggest

# keep a reference to highest
highest = people.at(0)

# whenever sort happened, go and check if the highest is changed
people.on "sort", ->
  current_highest = people.at(0)
  create_new_feed(highest) unless current_highest.cid is highest.cid

create_new_feed = (person)->
  feeds.create({name: person.get("name")})
```

Comment: @Michael: I don't think you mean java - this is http://coffeescript.org/, which is more like Python.

Comment: oh well its very object oriented.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Hi buddy, how's it going?

Comment: Hey sorry for keeping you waiting, I couldn't fully comprehend the code above. I decided to use backbone.js `hasChanged`, I had to create a new collection for this and I just listened if the `currentPoints` leader model changed value. This required me to create new routes/controllers/tables but it works well, and inside my `leadersCollection` I can add on to it.

Comment: It's a good answer I think, but I skipped all the coffee script tutorials while learning backbone.js and I did my best converting it into javascript, but even then I couldn't fully get what was going on. I was probably close though.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry I have improved my answer to fit in your case. I write coffeescript here just to show you the idea, as it's easy to see through. I think it makes more sense to keep a sorted collection instead of going your way by using `hasChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after studying how to use the `hasChanged` method, I decided to re-configure some code to allow me to simply use that method.

It only returns the attributes that are changed not the whole model, so if I am adding points to a model all I get in return is the points value, and that's no good.

So I created a new collection specifically for all the leaders/max and I simply check if `currentPoints` changes like below.

```
leadersCollection.each(function(model) {
    model.save({currentPoints: this.getMaxPointsPlayer().get('playerName')});
    if (model.hasChanged('currentPoints')) {

        //Here I add onto my apps feed, which adds a new item notifying the 
        //user there is a new leader
        feedCollection.create({
            feedItem: 'new leader', 
            playerName: model.get('currentPoints')
        });

    }
}, this);
```

Comment: but will you have a chance to create multiple `maxpoints` here since you loop through all models? and `hasChanged` could indicate a change to lower point also unless the points only increment.

Comment: Yeah they are only in increments, and there can only be one max player for each stat. It is just a live informational piece of data while the two teams are playing and the user is tracking the stats.

Comment: So I only have one row in the table, the only reason I do an each statement is so I can interact with the model, maybe in the future I need to reconfigure some things, but for now it is sufficient for my needs.